# How to split string into array, modify array then apply to string in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a string, after splitting into array and modified an item, how can I apply the change to the original string?

```
var str = "123,124,234,252",
    arrayStr = str.split(",");

arrayStr[3] = 25333;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could join the array with [`Array#join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join), the counter part of [`String#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

> The **`join()`** method joins all elements of an array into a string.

```js
var str = "123,124,234,252",
    arrayStr = str.split(",");

arrayStr[3] = 25333;
str = arrayStr.join(',');
console.log(str);
```